# Finding the differnce between two timestamps to get download time in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

I am trying to decode a Chrome history.sqlite file using python:

My Sql query is:

```
SELECT 
  datetime(start_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') AS 'Decoded start_time (local time)', 
  datetime(end_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') AS 'Decoded end_time (local time)' 
FROM downloads
```

my output is (there is more but for simplicity I just added one row):

```
2020-04-11 18:55:54 2020-04-11 18:57:34
```

I want to make a third column that provides we with the difference between the two timestamps (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `julianday()` like this:

```
SELECT t.*,
  round((julianday(t."Decoded end_time (local time)") - julianday(t."Decoded start_time (local time)")) * 24 * 60 * 60, 0)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    datetime(start_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') AS "Decoded start_time (local time)", 
    datetime(end_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') AS "Decoded end_time (local time)" 
  FROM downloads
) t
```

or with the function `strftime()`:

```
SELECT t.*,
  strftime('%s', t."Decoded end_time (local time)") - strftime('%s', t."Decoded start_time (local time)")
FROM (
  SELECT 
    datetime(start_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') AS "Decoded start_time (local time)", 
    datetime(end_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') AS "Decoded end_time (local time)" 
  FROM downloads
) t
```